# Null generic type c#

Tags: c#, generics, null

```
public class Node<E> : IPosition<E>
{
    private E element;
    public Node<E> PrevNode { get; set; }
    public Node<E> NextNode { get; set; }

    //Constructor
    public Node(E e, Node<E> p, Node<E> n)
    {
        element = e;
        PrevNode = p;
        NextNode = n;
    }
}
```

I have the above `Node` class which I want when I create a new node object, 
to be able to do this:

```
Node<E> n = new Node<E>(null, null, null);
```

This does not work since all types cannot be null in C#. What surprises me is when I try a similar thing in Java, it works! I have seen some relevant questions on Stack Overflow, but they do not give the result I want. I do not want to use the `default(E)`.

Comment: C# allows for generics to be used with primitive types, while Java only allows reference types with generics. All reference types can be null, so it works in Java.

Comment: `Node n = new Node(null, null, null);` you have to provide the specific type in order that to work.

Comment: `I do not need the default(E)` Don't you though?  How is that not *exactly* what you want?

Comment: Or something like `Node<int?> n = new Node<int?>(null, null, null);` where the type is nullable.

Comment: @Derek Not if that code is in the definition of `Node`; inside the class definition there *is* a type named `E`.

Comment: @Forecast So what do you *want* to have happen in the case of an integer?  You can't pass null because it's not a nullable type.

Comment: @Servy if i use the where E : class i can.

Comment: @Forecast No, if you do that then *you can't use an `int` at all*.  You've simply made the code cease to compile if anyone uses a non-nullable type, rather than allowing non-nullable types to have a null value.

Comment: @Servy how can i achieve that? I want to be able to pass non-nullable types...?

Comment: @Forecast Well you accepted an answer that prohibits you from ever using non-nullable types.  You shouldn't do that if you want to actually be able to use non-nullable types.  If you *do* want to be able to use non-nullable types, you need to describe what you want to happen.  They can't have a `null` value (by definition, because they're a non-nullable type).  What value *do* you want them to have?

Comment: @Servy well imagine building a linked list..i wanna be able to have some kind of unification in my code in order to avoid extra checks. For example in 
a linked list, the header i want it to be null.

Comment: That's not really enough information to give you an answer.

Comment: @Servy ok how the List<int> l1 = new List<int>() works? and it is possible for all data types at the same time string etc?

Comment: @Forecast You can look at the source code for a `List` yourself.  It never tries to store any `null` value in anything of type `T`, it only ever stores values of that type, which is what you should be doing as well.

Comment: @Servy ok i did roughly.What if i changed my node constructor to accept
Node(Object e, ...)? What kind of implications would that have to nullable types?.

Comment: @Forecast Your type is now no longer generic, and you've lost all static type checking.

Comment: @Servy Thank you for your guidance this requires some research...i will not waste your time further. This is enough for me to go on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148051/discussion-between-forecast-and-servy).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need a generic type constraint stating that `E` must be a reference type:

```
public class Node<E> : IPosition<E> where E : class
```

That is, unless you also need `E` to be a value type for other reasons. If that's the case, you need to sacrifice one requirement or the other.

Nullable value types are an option: With your original version, lacking the type constraint (because `Nullable<T>` is a value type itself), you could use `int?`. The following code compiles for me without the constraint:

```
var y = new Node<int?>(null, null, null);
```

`int?` isn't `int`, but it isn't exactly not `int`, is it?

Answer (score 2):

> What surprises me is when i try something similar in Java, it works.

This is because Java generic types are implemented with type erasure, which effectively means that they are all `java.lang.Object` descendants.

For example, you cannot use primitive `int` as your `Node`'s type argument in Java: you are forced to use `java.lang.Integer` instead. Hence, `element` can be assigned `null` regardless of `T`.

In C# there is no such limitation on type parameter: writing `Node<int>` is perfectly legal. However, with `element` of type `int` you can no longer write `element = null`, which is the root cause of the error that you see.

In addition to the `default(T)` approach that you mention, you could require that `T` is a reference type, like this:

```
public class Node<E> : IPosition<E> where E : class {
    ...
}
```

Now it is legal to pass `null` to the initial parameter of `Node`'s constructor, but it is illegal to instantiate `Node<T>` with any value type, including `Nullable<Tx>`.

Answer (score 1):

What if we do like this:

First of all create one simple interface

```
public interface IOptional<T>: IEnumerable<T> {}
```

And write implementation of it

```
public class Maybe<T>: IOptional<T>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<T> _element;
    public Maybe(T element)
        : this(new T[1] { element })
    {}
    public Maybe()
        : this(new T[0])
    {}
    private Maybe(T[] element)
    {
        _element = element;
    }
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _element.GetEnumerator();
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

After this we do some changes in your Node class

```
public class Node<E> : IPosition<E>
{
    private IOptional<E> element;
    public Node<E> PrevNode { get; set; }
    public Node<E> NextNode { get; set; }

    //Constructor
    public Node(IOptional<E> e, Node<E> p, Node<E> n)
    {
        element = e;
        PrevNode = p;
        NextNode = n;
    }
}
```

And use it

```
Node<E> n = new Node<E>(
                new Maybe<E>(), 
                null, 
                null
             );
```

> No more null checks inside Node class on this field

Instead of this

```
if (this.element != null) { .. }
```

Write like this

```
this.element.Select(e => { doSomething(e); return true; })
```

like this

```
if (this.element.Any()) 
{ 
    var elem = this.element.First();
    // do something
}
```

or write one small extension method

```
public static IOptional<TOutput> Match<TInput, TOutput>(
    this IEnumerable<TInput> maybe,
    Func<TInput, TOutput> some, Func<TOutput> nothing)
{
    if (maybe.Any())
    {
        return new Maybe<TOutput>(
                    some(
                        maybe.First()
                    )
                );
    }
    else
    {
        return new Maybe<TOutput>(
                    nothing()
                );
    }
}
```

and do like this

```
var result = this.element
                 .Match(
                     some: e => e.ToString(),
                     nothing: () => "Ups"
                 )
                 .First();
```

Comment: look my answer [about null object pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339729/generic-null-object-pattern-in-c-sharp/44789725#44789725)

Comment: I also recommend remove all null's in your code, especially
as parametres in constructor or methods